# Is it possible to seed data only not exists with typeorm-seeding?

Tags: typeorm, seeding

In ormconfig.ts, it can set `seeds` to point to a path for all the files.

```
  {
    ...
    seeds: ['db/seed/*.ts'],
  },
```

Is it possible to run only one file with an option like

```
$ npm run seed:run -f db/seed/file1.ts
```

In other words, if the data already been seeded into db, run it again will create duplicated data. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered this. What I did was check first if the data exists (get the records first then loop to each record), if not, push the `updates` to an array. Then call insert command with the `updates`.

```
const updates = [];
const records = await getRecords();
records.foreach(record => {
    if (!exists) updates.push(...);
});
await connection
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(TableName)
    .values(updates)
    .execute()
```